# How to access svg path attr when loaded from external source

Tags: javascript, svg

I use [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) to load an external svg image like that:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var image = s.image("images/ciag.svg", 0,0, 1140,193 );
```

image loads as it should and renders in DOM like here:
[image]
Now i need to access its `path` attribute in order to animate it. I don't want to put the svg code into my HTML markup because it's couple of hundred lines long and my HTML becomes obfuscated.

How do I acces it?

Comment: You can't access the DOM of an image, you'd need to include it via an object, iframe or embed tag if you wanted to do that.

Comment: You can't access path of the svg if it's an image. You will need to load the file using ajax and insert it to the DOM.